# SharePoint 2013 breadcrumbs trimming home link

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am using the below snippet to get breadcrumbs in my masterpage on a branded site. What I like to do is either hide or trim the the first link (highlighted in red) which is the the homepage link (see screenshot). The second link is the name of the page which is what I like to show minus the first link (homepage link). How would I accomplish this? Any suggestion or workarounds would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to achieve this, from CSS only, to overrides in C#, among others.

The following StackOverflow post explains many methods that are valid to achieve this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050610/how-can-i-hide-the-sitemappath-root-node-on-home-page